# d3 linechart - Show 0 on the y-axis without passing in all points?

Tags: d3.js, linechart

I have a line chart. Its purpose is to show the amount of transactions per user over a given time period.

To do this I'm getting the dates of all users transactions. I'm working off this example : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955 and have the line chart renedering fine.

My x-axis is time and the y-axis is number of transactions. The problem I have is to do with displaying dates when there is no activity.

Say I have 4 transactions on Tuesday and 5 transactions on Thursday..I need to show that there has been 0 transactions on Wednesday. As no data exists in my database explicitly stating that a user has made no transactions on Wedensday do I need to pass in the Wednesday time (and all other times, depending on the timeframe) with a 0 value? or can I do it with d3? I can't seem to find any examples that fit my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a pretty common issue, so I worked up an example implementation here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/dhW2F/2/

Relevant code:

```
  // get the min/max dates
  var extent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }),
      // hash the existing days for easy lookup
      dateHash = data.reduce(function(agg, d) {
          agg[d.date] = true;
          return agg;
      }, {}),
      // note that this leverages some "get all headers but date" processing
      // already present in the example
      headers = color.domain();

    // make even intervals
    d3.time.days(extent[0], extent[1])
        // drop the existing ones
        .filter(function(date) {
            return !dateHash[date];
        })
        // and push them into the array
        .forEach(function(date) {
            var emptyRow = { date: date };
            headers.forEach(function(header) {
                emptyRow[header] = null;
            });
            data.push(emptyRow);
        });
    // re-sort the data
    data.sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.date, b.date); });
```

As you can see, it's a bit convoluted, but seems to work well - you make an array of evenly spaced dates using the handy `d3.interval.range` method, filter out those dates already present in your data, and use the remaining ones to push empty rows. One downside is that performance could be slow for a big dataset - and this assumes full rows are empty, rather than different empty dates in different series.

An alternate representation, with gaps (using `line.defined`) instead of zero points, is here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/dhW2F/3/