# dc.js lineChart - fill missing dates and show zero where no data

Tags: dc.js, linechart

I have a dc.js lineChart that is showing the number of events per hour. I would like rather than joining the line between two known values the value should be shown as zero.

So for the data below I would like to have the line drop to zero for 10AM

```
{datetime: "2018-05-01 09:10:00", event: 1}
{datetime: "2018-05-01 11:30:00", event: 1}
{datetime: "2018-05-01 11:45:00", event: 1}
{datetime: "2018-05-01 12:15:00", event: 1}

var eventsByDay = facts.dimension(function(d) { return d3.time.hour(d.datetime);});
var eventsByDayGroup = eventsByDay.group().reduceCount(function(d) { return d.datetime; });
```

I've had a look at defined but don't think that is right, I think I need to add the zero value into the data for each hour that has no data? However I'm not sure how to go about it and I can't seem to find an example of what I'm trying within dc.js

This other question does answer this but for d3.js and I'm unsure how to translate that - [d3 linechart - Show 0 on the y-axis without passing in all points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733601/d3-linechart-show-0-on-the-y-axis-without-passing-in-all-points)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to add the data before filtering by using ensure_group_bins(eventsByDayGroup) but that isn't getting the correct results either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track with `ensure_group_bins` but instead of knowing the required set of bins beforehand, in this case we need to calculate them.

Luckily d3 provides [interval.range](https://github.com/d3/d3-time/blob/master/README.md#interval_range) which returns an array of dates for every interval boundary between two dates.

Then we need to merge-sort that set with the bins from the original group. Perhaps I have over-engineered this slightly, but here is a function to do that:

```
function fill_intervals(group, interval) {
  return {
    all: function() {
      var orig = group.all().map(kv => ({key: new Date(kv.key), value: kv.value}));
      var target = interval.range(orig[0].key, orig[orig.length-1].key);
      var result = [];
      for(var oi = 0, ti = 0; oi < orig.length && ti < target.length;) {
        if(orig[oi].key <= target[ti]) {
          result.push(orig[oi]);
          if(orig[oi++].key.valueOf() === target[ti].valueOf())
            ++ti;
        } else {
          result.push({key: target[ti], value: 0});
          ++ti;
        }
      }
      if(oi<orig.length)
        Array.prototype.push.apply(result, orig.slice(oi));
      if(ti<target.length)
        Array.prototype.push.apply(result, target.slice(ti).map(t => ({key: t, value: 0})));
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

Basically we iterate over both the original bins and the target bins, and take whichever is lower. If they are the same, then we increment both counters; otherwise we just increment the lower one.

Finally, when either array has run out, we append all remaining results from the other array.

[Here is an example fiddle based on your code.](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/3vj1nvn9/20/)

It's written in D3v4 but you should only have to change `d3.timeHour` in two places to `d3.time.hour` to use it with D3v3.

I'll add this function to the FAQ!