# dc.js series chart - chart is too slow when filling missing data

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I would like to create a multi time line chart as a series chart.

I read the Stack Overflow regarding filling missing data 
[dc.js lineChart - fill missing dates and show zero where no data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50296863/dc-js-linechart-fill-missing-dates-and-show-zero-where-no-data)

Question: I implemented the code there and it worked great for a single line chart. For a series chart I needed to tweak it a bit. It works, however the performance is terrible.

Here is the sample data we are using:

```
let data = [{description: "Walmart", location: "40.216403 -74.541296", timeReported: 1581710670184}
 {description: "Target", location: "38.271996 -84.032575", timeReported: 1583524065011}
 {description: "Wendys", location: "39.255831 -75.532763", timeReported: 1583524065011}
 {description: "7-11", location: "34.925349 -78.463977", timeReported: 1583524065011}
 {description: "WaWa", location: "35.716208 -77.741230", timeReported: 1583524065013}
 {description: "7-11", location: "41.258950 -83.888060", timeReported: 1583524065013}
 {description: "Shell", location: "37.879694 -79.836127", timeReported: 1583524065011}
 {description: "Dominos", location: "35.890273 -80.700329", timeReported: 1583524065395}
 {description: "Dominos", location: "39.268777 -78.743366", timeReported: 1583524065397}
 {description: "Walgreens", location: "35.490215 -81.773863", timeReported: 1583524065399}
 {description: "7-11", location: "37.974797 -81.393449", timeReported: 1583524065506}
 {description: "Wendys", location: "40.859685 -76.963065", timeReported: 1583524065521}
 {description: "CVS", location: "38.517910 -78.251419", timeReported: 1583524065553}
 {description: "CVS", location: "35.947033 -81.616061", timeReported: 1583524142169}
 {description: "Shell", location: "39.566535 -77.992499", timeReported: 1583524142176}
 {description: "Target", location: "37.832142 -88.003151", timeReported: 1583524142170}
 {description: "Wendys", location: "40.245397 -80.061998", timeReported: 1583524142223}
 {description: "Macys", location: "39.631265 -75.157194", timeReported: 1583524142223}
 {description: "Macys", location: "36.631458 -77.803286", timeReported: 1583524142213}
 {description: "7-11", location: "36.249754 -79.830006", timeReported: 1583524142251}
 {description: "7-11", location: "41.138285 -83.298142", timeReported: 1583524142249}
 {description: "Wendys", location: "34.940485 -77.230388", timeReported: 1583524142249}
 {description: "7-11", location: "39.605373 -77.448768", timeReported: 1583524142296}
 {description: "Wendys", location: "35.609094 -79.455712", timeReported: 1583524142293}
 {description: "WaWa", location: "37.130753 -78.076709", timeReported: 1583524142310}
 {description: "Macys", location: "40.058482 -78.497258", timeReported: 1583524142338}
 {description: "Wendys", location: "39.255831 -75.532763", timeReported: 1582058735883}
 {description: "Macys", location: "39.631265 -75.157194", timeReported: 1582058735883}
 {description: "7-11", location: "36.249754 -79.830006", timeReported: 1582058735883}
 {description: "7-11", location: "39.605373 -77.448768", timeReported: 1582058735883}
 {description: "Wendys", location: "35.609094 -79.455712", timeReported: 1582058735883}
 {description: "WaWa", location: "37.130753 -78.076709", timeReported: 1582058735883}
 {description: "Macys", location: "40.058482 -78.497258", timeReported: 1582058735883}
 {description: "Kohls", location: "40.373533 -101.057470", timeReported: 1582838559493}]
```

Here is the sample code. BTW, curTimeInterval in the code below is just an alias for d3 timeIntervlas which can be chosen by user. (d3.timeHour, d3.timeDay, d3.timeWeek, d3.timeMonth).

```
cf = crossfilter(data);

dateDim = cf.dimension((d) => {
  return curTimeInterval(d.timeReportedDate);
});
reportedGroup = dateDim.group().reduceSum((d) => 1);


let minDate = d3.min(reportedGroup.all(), (kv) => {
  return kv.key;
});
let maxDate = d3.max(reportedGroup.all(), (kv) => {
  return kv.key;
});
minDate = curTimeInterval.offset(minDate, -2);
maxDate = curTimeInterval.offset(maxDate, 2);

const runDimension = cf.dimension((d) => {
  return [d.description, curTimeInterval(d.timeReportedDate)];
});


const runGroup = runDimension.group();

// Fills the missing data in the group
const filledSeries = fill_composite_intervals(runGroup, curTimeInterval);

const seriesChart = new dc.SeriesChart('#series');
seriesChart
  .width(768)
  .height(480)
  .chart(function(c) {
    return new dc.LineChart(c).curve(d3.curveCardinal);
  })
  .x(d3.scaleTime().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
  .xUnits(curTimeInterval.range)
  .brushOn(false)
  .clipPadding(10)
  .elasticY(true)
  .dimension(runDimension)
  .group(filledSeries)
  .mouseZoomable(true)
  .seriesAccessor((d) => {
    return d.key[0];
  })
  .keyAccessor((d) => {
    return d.key[1];
  })
  .valueAccessor((d) => {
    return d.value;
  })
  .legend(dc.legend().x(350).y(350).itemHeight(13).gap(5).horizontal(1).legendWidth(140).itemWidth(70))
  .yAxis()
  .tickValues(d3.range(min > 0 ? min - 1 : min, max + 1));

seriesChart.margins().left += 40;


fill_composite_intervals = (group, interval) => {
  return {
    all: function() {
      const retVal = [];
      const allArray = group.all();
      if (!allArray.length) {
        return retVal;
      }
      allArray.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.key[1].getTime() < b.key[1].getTime()) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (a.key[1].getTime() > b.key[1].getTime()) {
          return 1;
        }
        // a must be equal to b
        return 0;
      });
      const target = interval.range(allArray[0].key[1], allArray[allArray.length-1].key[1]);
      const allMap = new Map();
      allArray.forEach((obj) => {
        let innerArray = allMap.get(obj.key[0]);
        if (!innerArray) {
          innerArray = [];
          allMap.set(obj.key[0], innerArray);
        }
        innerArray.push({key: obj.key[1], value: obj.value});
      });
      allMap.forEach((value, key, map) => {
        const orig = value.map((kv) => ({key: new Date(kv.key), value: kv.value}));

        const result = [];
        if (orig.length) {

          let oi;
          let ti;
          for (oi = 0, ti = 0; oi < orig.length && ti < target.length;) {
            if (orig[oi].key <= target[ti]) {
              result.push(orig[oi]);
             if (orig[oi++].key.valueOf() === target[ti].valueOf()) {
                ++ti;
              }
            } else {
              result.push({key: target[ti], value: 0});
              ++ti;
            }
          }
          if (oi<orig.length) {
            Array.prototype.push.apply(result, orig.slice(oi));
          }
          if (ti<target.length) {
            Array.prototype.push.apply(result, target.slice(ti).map((t) => ({key: t, value: 0})));
          }
        }
        map.set(key, result);
      });

      allMap.forEach((value, key, map) => {
        value.forEach((obj) => {
          const newObj = {
            key: [key, obj.key],
            value: obj.value
          };

          retVal.push(newObj);
        });
      });
            return retVal;
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: You don't say which interval you are using for this data. I wrote [an example of choosing the appropriate interval](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/v7ujq0de/214/), which demonstrates the problem of using too fine an interval. For this data, timeDay produces 240 bins, timeHour produces 5542 bins, and timeMinute produces 332482 bins. There is no reason to show more points than the width in pixels; also I have turned off `xyTipsOn` in this demo because every dot is drawn hidden. Hope to follow up with a thorough answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

I started out by creating [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/v7ujq0de/221/) which illustrates the problem. The interesting thing here is a select menu which shows which time intervals are appropriate for the data and zoom level (domain) of the chart.

It isn't appropriate to show more than width/2 points (since they won't be rendered), and it's also not appropriate to show less than two points, so the "inappropriate" options are greyed italic:

[image: fiddle illustrating appropriate/inappropriate intervals]

It uses an object mapping interval names to the number of milliseconds in the corresponding d3 interval:

```
const intervals = {
  timeSecond: 1000,
  timeMinute: 60000,
  timeHour: 3600000,
  timeDay: 86400000,
  timeWeek: 604800000,
  timeMonth: 2628000000,
  timeYear: 31536000000
}
```

`allowed_intervals` determines the first and last appropriate interval:

```
function allowed_intervals(chart, intervals, dateDomain) {
  const dt = dateDomain[1].getTime() - dateDomain[0].getTime(),
    first = Object.entries(intervals).find(
        ([iname, ms]) => dt / ms < chart.width() / 2);
  if(!first)
    throw new Error('date range too long')
  const last = Object.entries(intervals).reverse().find(
     ([iname, ms]) => d3[iname](dateDomain[0]).getTime() !== d3[iname](dateDomain[1]).getTime());
  return [first[0],last[0]];
}
```

So that's all well and great. The example prints the resulting data, and we can see that if we fill the example data with `d3.timeMinute` it produces 332482 data points from the original 15. That's clearly way too much data, especially for a simple example.

This is an okay algorithm for finding the appropriate d3 time interval. However it fails when we enable zooming, because now we can zoom into a single hour, say, where `timeMinute` is appropriate, but if you use that interval for all the data, it's way too many points and the chart slows down to a halt.

So I started thinking about how to make it more efficient. We don't actually need to fill every missing time interval. We really need is to make sure we catch the **falling edge**, when data goes from non-zero to zero, and the **rising edge**, where the data goes from zero to non-zero. We only need to add zeros to the input data in those cases.

Here is a new version of `fill_composite_intervals` that uses the rising and falling edges, only adding as many zeros as are necessary to display these edges:

```
// input: a group with keys [category, time] and numeric values; a d3 time interval
// output: the same, but with zeroes filled in per the interval
function fill_composite_intervals(group, interval) {
  return {
    all: function() {
      const retVal = [];
      const allArray = group.all().slice();
      if (!allArray.length) {
        return retVal;
      }
      // make sure input data is sorted
      allArray.sort((a, b) => a.key[1].getTime() - b.key[1].getTime());

      // find all time intervals within the data
      // pad at both ends to add leading and trailing zeros
      const target = interval.range(interval.offset(allArray[0].key[1], -1),
        interval.offset(allArray[allArray.length-1].key[1], 2));

      // separate the data for each category
      const allMap = new Map();
      allArray.forEach(({key: [cat, time], value}) => {
        let innerArray = allMap.get(cat);
        if (!innerArray) {
          innerArray = [];
          allMap.set(cat, innerArray);
        }
        innerArray.push({key: time, value});
      });

      // walk each category, adding leading and trailing zeros
      allMap.forEach((value, key, map) => {
        const orig = value.map(({key, value}) => ({key: new Date(key), value}));

        const result = [];
        if (orig.length) {
          let oi = 0, ti = 0, last_filled = false, skipped_fill = false;
          while(oi < orig.length && ti < target.length) {
            if (orig[oi].key <= target[ti]) {
              if(skipped_fill) {
                // in the last iteration, we skipped a zero
                // so add one now (rising edge)
                result.push({key: target[ti-1], value: 0});
                skipped_fill = false;
              }
              result.push(orig[oi]);
              if (orig[oi++].key.getTime() === target[ti].getTime()) {
                ++ti;
              }
              last_filled = false;
            } else {
              if(!last_filled) {
                // last iteration we pushed a value
                // so push a zero now (falling edge)
                result.push({key: target[ti], value: 0});
                last_filled = true;
              }
              else skipped_fill = true;
              ++ti;
            }
          }
          if (oi<orig.length) {
            Array.prototype.push.apply(result, orig.slice(oi));
          }
          if (ti<target.length) {
            // add one trailing zero at the end
            result.push({key: target[ti], value: 0});
          }
        }
        map.set(key, result);
      });

      allMap.forEach((value, key, map) => {
        value.forEach(({key: time, value}) => {
          retVal.push({
            key: [key, time],
            value
          });
        });
      });
      return retVal;
    }
  };
}
```

See the comments in the code for an explanation. It only produces data proportionate to the input data, e.g. 67 points for the input 15 with `timeMinute`, instead of 300+K.

Interestingly, I found that `d3.curveCardinal` produces strange artifacts when there are less zeros. Intuitively, I think the line gains too much "momentum" if points are skipped. So I chose [d3.curveMonotoneX](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curveMonotoneX) instead. I think it is more appropriate anyway.

```
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
```

I also padded the `interval.range` at the beginning and end so that the data would start and end at zero, which is more appealing.

This example is still slow when you select `d3.timeSecond` (it still iterates through 300+K points) but it seems to perform okay up to `timeMinute`, which seems to capture the resolution of this data.

Further possible improvements:

1. add more leading and trailing zeros so that the curves are consistent / symmetric
2. stop using `interval.range` so that not so many points are calculated and thrown away; instead, detect rising and falling edges using `interval.offset` and next/last data points only (tricky!)

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/01pc69rz/85/).
[image: screenshot - more efficient; leading/trailing edges]

Answer (score 1):

Since my previous answer was still too slow when used with small time intervals, I rewrote the core of the loop.

Rather than walking the entire range of dates between the beginning and end, it's much faster and much simpler to just look at the data and detect whether one or two zeros should be added between the last data point and this one.

The heart of `fill_composite_intervals` now looks like

```
  const [begin, end] = d3.extent(allArray, ({key}) => key[1]).map(interval);

  // walk each category, adding leading and trailing zeros
  allMap.forEach((value, key, map) => {
    const orig = value.map(({key, value}) => ({key: new Date(key), value}));

    const result = [];
    if (orig.length) {
      let last = interval.offset(begin, -2);
      for(let oi = 0; oi < orig.length; ++oi) {
        const count = interval.count(last, orig[oi].key);
        if(count === 0 || count === 1) ;
        else {
          result.push({key: interval.offset(last, 1), value: 0});
          if(count > 2)
            result.push({key: interval.offset(orig[oi].key, -1), value: 0});
        }
        result.push(orig[oi]);
        last = orig[oi].key;
      }
      result.push({key: interval.offset(orig[orig.length-1].key, 1), value: 0});
    }
    map.set(key, result);
  });
```

[Faster fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/7szywf69/29/).

#### Update: smoother, symmetric curves

The first and last curves are misshapen because they are missing a control point on the spline to make the slope 0 at the edges.

We can add one more zero at the beginning and end.

Here is the fast and smooth fake group for multi time line charts.

```
function fill_composite_intervals(group, interval) {
  return {
    all: function() {
      const retVal = [];
      const allArray = group.all().slice();
      if (!allArray.length) {
        return retVal;
      }
      // make sure input data is sorted
      allArray.sort((a, b) => a.key[1].getTime() - b.key[1].getTime());

      // separate the data for each category
      const allMap = new Map();
      allArray.forEach(({key: [cat, time], value}) => {
        let innerArray = allMap.get(cat);
        if (!innerArray) {
          innerArray = [];
          allMap.set(cat, innerArray);
        }
        innerArray.push({key: time, value});
      });


      // walk each category, adding leading and trailing zeros
      allMap.forEach((value, key, map) => {
        const orig = value.map(({key, value}) => ({key: new Date(key), value}));

        const result = [];
        if (orig.length) {
          let last = interval.offset(orig[0].key, -3);
          for(let oi = 0; oi < orig.length; ++oi) {
            const count = interval.count(last, orig[oi].key);
            if(count === 0 || count === 1) ;
            else {
              result.push({key: interval.offset(last, 1), value: 0});
              if(count > 2)
                result.push({key: interval.offset(orig[oi].key, -1), value: 0});
            }
            result.push(orig[oi]);
            last = orig[oi].key;
          }
          result.push(
            {key: interval.offset(orig[orig.length-1].key, 1), value: 0},
            {key: interval.offset(orig[orig.length-1].key, 2), value: 0},
          );
        }
        map.set(key, result);
      });

      allMap.forEach((value, key, map) => {
        value.forEach(({key: time, value}) => {
          retVal.push({
            key: [key, time],
            value
          });
        });
      });
      return retVal;
    }
  };
}
```

[image: smoother, symmetric curves]
[Smoother fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/at0d74cb/4/).