# d3 break line graph if no data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter, linegraph

I am using dc to create a line graph where capacity is on the y-axis and week is on the x-axis. For weeks, the range is 1-52, but there is no data from weeks 2-40. I only have data for week 1 and 41-52, but my line graph is still creating a line when there is no data:

[image]

How do I get it so the line graph will break if there are no values? So it wouldn't be one connected line. Here is my code for reference

```
let chart = dc.lineChart("#chart");
let ndx = crossfilter(results);
            
let weekDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
     return d.week = +d.week;
});
                
function reduceAdd(p, v) {
    ++p.count;
    p.total += v.capacity;
    p.average = p.total / p.count;
    return p;
}

function reduceRemove(p, v) {
    --p.count;
    p.total -= v.capacity;
    p.average = p.count ? p.total / p.count : 0;
    return p;
}

function reduceInitial() {
    return { count: 0, total: 0, average: 0 };
} 

let capacityGroup = weekDimension.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);
            
chart.width(360)
    .height(200)
    .margins({ top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 30 })
    .mouseZoomable(false)
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([1, 52]))
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .brushOn(false)
    .dimension(weekDimension)
    .valueAccessor(function (d) {
        return d.value.average;
    })
    .group(capacityGroup);

dc.renderAll('chart');
```

This is how `results` would look like

```
{month : "1", capacity: "48"}
{month : "1", capacity: "60"}
{month : "42", capacity: "67"}
{month : "42", capacity: "60"}
{month : "43", capacity: "66"}
{month : "44", capacity: "52"}
{month : "45", capacity: "63"}
{month : "46", capacity: "67"}
{month : "47", capacity: "80"}
{month : "48", capacity: "61"}
{month : "48", capacity: "66"}
{month : "49", capacity: "54"}
{month : "50", capacity: "69"}
```

I have tried to add `.defined(d => { return d.y != null; });` and `.defined(d => !isNaN(d.value));` but that didn't do anything... Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you have data points in your array where `d.y == null`? If not, how is the scale to know that a value is missing?

Comment: What @AndrewReid said: dc.js will only display the data it receives. It doesn't know what data "should" be there. [Here is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50337225/676195), the difference being that you want to fill with `null` instead of 0.

Comment: Ah that makes sense... @Gordon how would I incorporate that in my code?

Comment: It’s a fake group, so you can use the function to wrap your group before you pass it to the chart. If you can’t figure it out, please edit your question and add enough to reproduce what you have so far (preferably a fiddle, bl.ock, or other notebook, or at least sample data). I’ll post an answer if you do.

Comment: @Gordon I edited my question with how my code looks like -- Let me know if you need anything else for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, the important problem is that dc.js will only draw the data it receives. It doesn't know if data is missing, so we will need to fill in the `null`s in order to draw gaps in the line.

I linked to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50337225/676195), where the data is timestamps. The answer there uses a [d3 time interval](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#time-intervals-d3-time) to generate the missing timestamps.

However, your data uses integers for keys (even though it represents weeks), so we will need to change the function a little bit:

```
function fill_ints(group, fillval, stride = 1) { // 1
    return {
      all: function() {
        var orig = group.all();
        var target = d3.range(orig[0].key, orig[orig.length-1].key, stride); // 2
        var result = [];
        for(var oi = 0, ti = 0; oi < orig.length && ti < target.length;) {
          if(orig[oi].key <= target[ti]) {
            result.push(orig[oi]);
            if(orig[oi++].key === target[ti])
              ++ti;
          } else {
            result.push({key: target[ti], value: fillval});
            ++ti;
          }
        } // 3
        if(oi<orig.length) // 4
          Array.prototype.push.apply(result, orig.slice(oi));
        if(ti<target.length) // 5
          result = [...result, ...target.slice(ti).map(t => ({key: t, value: fillval}))];
        return result;
      }
    };
}
```

1. This function takes a group, the value to fill, and a stride, i.e. the desired gap between entries.
2. It reads the current data, and generates the desired keys using [d3.range](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/v2.9.1/README.md#range).
3. It walks both arrays, adding any missing entries to a copy of the group data.
4. If there are any leftover entries from the original group data, it appends it.
5. If there are any remaining targets, it generates those.

Now we wrap our original group using this function, creating a ["fake group"](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups):

```
const filledGroup = fill_ints(capacityGroup, {average: null});
```

and pass it to the chart instead:

```
.group(filledGroup);
```

One weakness of using [LineChart.defined()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/LineChart.html#defined), and the underlying [d3.line.defined](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/v2.0.0/README.md#line_defined), is that it takes two points to make a line. If you have isolated points, as week 1 is isolated in your original data, then it won't be shown at all.

In [this demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/mqu2v16s/33/), I have avoided the problem by adding data for week 2.

[image: screenshot with non-isolated disjoint points]

#### But what about isolated dots?

I was curious how to solve the "isolated dots problem" so I tried showing the built-in dots that are usually used for a mouseover effect:

```
chart.on('pretransition', chart => {
    const all = chart.group().all();
  isolated = all.reduce((p, kv, i) => {
    return (kv.value.average !== null &&
    (i==0 || all[i-1].value.average == null) &&
      ((i==all.length-1 || all[i+1].value.average == null))) ?
      {...p, [kv.key]: true} : p;      
  }, {});
  chart.g().selectAll('circle.dot')
    .filter(d => isolated[d.data.key])
    .style('fill-opacity', 0.75)
    .on('mousemove mouseout', null)
})
```

[This works](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/mqu2v16s/85/) but it currently relies on disabling the interactivity of those dots so they don't disappear.

[image: with isolated data as dots]

Comment: Forgot to respond but thank you so much! This works perfectly and is exactly what i needed